# How do I connect multiple tables and return the result back to the screen?

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables:

```
users (id, username, password);
topics (id, uid, name, date);
subjects (id, uid, tid, name, date);
posts (id, sid, tid, content, date);
```

I'd like to echo every topic with the number of subjects and posts in it, order by date.

My query looks like this:

```
$tquery = 'SELECT users.id, users.username, 
                  topics.id, topics.name, topics.date, topics.uid, 
                  subjects.tid, subjects.id, posts.sid FROM topics
               INNER JOIN users ON topics.uid = users.id
               INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.tid = topics.id
               INNER JOIN posts ON posts.sid = subjects.id
           ORDER BY topics.date DESC';
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $tquery);
```

The PHP code I'm using for echoing the topics out is the following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo '<table><tr class="heading">
                <th title="Hozzáadta: admin '.$row["username"].'"><a href="/php/forum/topics.php?id='.$row["id"].'" class="topic-title">'.$row["name"].'</a></th>
                <th>Témák: '.count($row["tid"]).'</th>
                <th>Hozzászólások: '.count($row["sid"]).'</th>
                <th>Hozzáadva: '.$row["date"].'</th>
            </tr></table>';
}
```

Unfortunately it's wrong because it gives back tables with the same topic name and it doesn't do the counting of the subjects and posts as well. Please help me I've stucked days ago with this problem.

Comment: We know the structure of the table. We have no idea about what data you want to get from it. Please provide that if you want an answer.

Comment: Sorry!

I'd like to echo out a table with all of the topics and the subjects and posts there are inside each one of the topics.

Example: The cars topic has 3 subjects and 12 posts in it. The movies topic has 1 subject and 7 posts in it. I'd like to echo out the following:

Topic name = Cars
Subjects = 3
Posts = 12

Topic name = Movies
Subjects = 1
Posts = 7

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` and `count` in SQL while not in php:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, topics.id, topics.name, topics.date, topics.uid, count(subjects.tid), subjects.id, count(posts.sid) FROM topics
left JOIN users ON topics.uid = users.id
left JOIN subjects ON subjects.tid = topics.id
left JOIN posts ON posts.sid = subjects.id
group by topics.id
ORDER BY topics.date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It displays the topics now in a right way, but unfortunately it displays 4 subjects while there are only 3 in my database.

One more question: how do I echo the subjects under each topic? Should I try one more while loop inside the main while?

I'd like to have this result:

Cars    subjects:3    posts: 12   date
  Lamborghini
  Aston Martin
  Ferrari

Comment: use loop in loop is a very low efficient way. try to use one query to get the results, and filter them to 3 subjects' array in a loop.